# Google Icon(Logo) for Sign_in flutter

Tags: flutter, icons, google-signin

I'm trying to add google logo for sign in with google by downloading from https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines. But when I use it in flutter app, some lines and dots are appearing around logo.

```
GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: _size.height * 0.016),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                          ),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                // decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  'assets/images/google_icon/btn_google_light_normal.9.png',
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 5.0,
                              ),
                              Text('Sign-in with Google')
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

which results in

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqonS.png)

or

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9krbF.png)

How to remove glitches around the G logo?

Answer (score 3):

i think there may be problem in the format of image you are using try out this code

```
Container(
  width:300,
  height:80,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        // decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
          child:
          Image.network(
              'http://pngimg.com/uploads/google/google_PNG19635.png',
              fit:BoxFit.cover
          )                  
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 5.0,
      ),
      Text('Sign-in with Google')
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is not the most elegant solution, but I just cropped  the original image to get rid of the lines.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use an open-source background remover tool such as [remove.bg/upload](https://www.remove.bg/upload) to remove everything around the logo. Then, you can just do the same thing: `Image.network('<your path>', height: 40, width: 40)` or any size.